# Very weird interaction between lineno and mathtools

Tags: mathtools, lineno

The following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[1]
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
Test, hi!
\end{document}
```

gives multiple errors about e.g., `\equation*` being already defined:

```
Command \gather already defined. }
Command \gather* already defined. }
Command \alignat already defined. }
Command \alignat* already defined. }
Command \align already defined. }
Command \align* already defined. }
Command \flalign already defined. }
Command \flalign* already defined. }
Command \multline already defined. }
Command \multline* already defined. ...tart@multline\st@rredtrue}{\endmultline}
Command \equation* already defined. }
```

Using

- Package: lineno 2022/07/30 line numbers on paragraphs v5.0
- Package: mathtools 2022/06/29 v1.29 mathematical typesetting tools

Comment: load lineno later.

Comment: Yes, that does it. Thanks.

Comment: I've sent a suggestion to the author of `lineno` suggesting that this information might be added to the documentation, along with the very nice documentation about changes on account of `amsmath` in `lineno` v.5.0.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot @barbarabeeton !

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I had the same issue and loading lineno later solved it immediately. Thanks a lot!